# Fix recursive array

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make an array to store the calculated numbers in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441282/make-an-array-to-store-the-calculated-numbers-in-memory)

I have to modify some code to do some new things.

**These are the new requirements:**

-The program will need to use an array in which to store the calculated Fibonacci numbers in memory. (Which can be a globe variable)

-The numbers array is also considered to be a partially-filled array and therefore I will need to declare a variable to keep track of the number of items which has been stored in the array.

-The numbers array should be declared to have 46 positions.

-The number 46 should be declared as a global constant named MAXFIB, and therefore the number 46 should not appear in my program more than once.

-At the start of your program, the numbers array needs to be initialized with the "starting knowledge"(The Base cases)- the first two Fibonacci numbers are 1 and 1. Store these into the first two array positions.

-Add an additional set of base cases so that if the "n" parameter value is too low or too high then the function will stop and return -1, indicating an error condition.

-Add an additional base case so that if the Fibonacci number we are looking for is already stored in the array, then I simply need to retrieve it from the array and return it.

-For the recursive case, it will still need to call on the function two times recursively as it did before, but after the number has been calculated, I will need to store it into the array before returning.

**This is my code so far:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Returns the nth number in the fibonacci sequence
int fib(int n, int* memory);

const int MAXFIB = 46;

int main()
{
    int memory[MAXFIB];

    memory[0] = 1;
    memory[1] = 1;

    cout << fib(46) << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int fib(int n, int* memory)
{
    // Base cases
    if (n < 1 || n > MAXFIB) return -1;

    if (n == memory) return memory;

    // Recursive cases
    memory[n] = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
    return;

}
```

So, my question is, what am I doing right and doing wrong? What do I need to correct and or finish?

Thanks

Comment: You have unusual requirements.  Homework?

Comment: Have you tried to compile your code? What do the error messages tell you about your code?

Comment: At least try to compile your code before asking.

Answer (score 1):

Not super proficient the particular language, but in your method call to fib you are only putting 46. In your definition for fib() you have two parameters specified. Maybe in the method call, add the parameter to fill int* memory.

Again..not proficient in the language. Just a possibility.

Comment: While the C++ tag is definitely one where you _must_ be proficient in the language to answer questions, this answer is correct for as much as it answers

Comment: What do you mean "to fill int* memory"?

Comment: int fib(int n, int* memory)
{
 This is how you defined the function
..when you call this function from your main() you only call it as fib(46) you need fib(46, someInt)

Answer (score 1):

why are you using 46
cout << fib(46) << endl;

you can use 
cout << fib(MAXFIB) << endl;
easy to change in future